# Django, html template, POST submit form not working

Tags: django, forms, templates, submit

The 'Submit' button in this form, in this Django project, does not seem to do anything. I cannot spot the logic error in the code or files.

**sign.html** (this is the page that displays). On clicking the submit button, it does nothing, but it should populate the database.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'guestbook/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Tell the world how you're doing!</h1>
<h2>Sign the guestbook</h2>
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="{% url 'sign' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
  Enter your name:<br>
  <!--<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name here">-->
   {{form.name}}
  <br>
 Enter your comment:<br>
  <!--<textarea name="message" type="Textarea" placeholder="Your comment here" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>-->
  {{form.comment}}
  <br><br>

  <input type="button" value="Submit">

</form> 


<p>Go to the <a href="{% url 'index' %}"> guestbook </a> itself</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect the problem is in the code below or possibly in the views.py file, but as it is not throwing any exceptions I cannot find it.

It is the sign function below that is the relevant one to this question.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Comment

from .forms import CommentForm

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    comments = Comment.objects.order_by('-date_added')
    context ={'comments': comments}
    #name=Name.objects.order_by('-date_added')

    #return render(request,'guestbook/index.html')
    return render(request,'guestbook/index.html', context)


def sign(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_comment=Comment(name=request.POST['name'],comment=request.POST['comment'])
            new_comment.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    context={'form' : form}
    return render(request,'guestbook/sign.html',context)
```

The models file creates the model for the name and comment which is to be saved to the database.

And finally, **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Comment(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    comments=models.TextField()
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    



"""
{% for c in comment %}
{% endfor %}
"""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A form is submitted by a button which type is submit inside

```
<form>
    <!-- button goes here and input fields also -->
</form>
```

Change this

```
<input type="button" value="Submit">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Then in **views.py**
Change this `new_comment=Comment(name=request.POST['name'],comment=request.POST['comment'])`
To

```
new_comment = Comment()
new_comment.name = request.POST.get("name")
new_comment.comments = request.POST.get("comment")
new_comment.save()
```

Comment: Odd, it is now coming up with the error: TypeError: Comment() got an unexpected keyword argument 'comment'

Comment: That means your forms working. Now issue is in your code `            new_comment=Comment(name=request.POST['name'],comment=request.POST['comment'])
`

Comment: There isn't any issue with that line though ...so to solve the problem, I need to know what it is. It simply posts the error above, but I can see no problem in this code.

Comment: Then check is any form data receive in request.POST

Comment: you should be using `form.cleaned_data['name']` and `form.cleaned_data['comment']`, not the `POST` data directly, for safety reasons. Also the field on the model is `comments`, not `comment` which explains the `TypeError`.

Comment: Suggesting a  TypeError ...but cannot see what to change!

Comment: The error tells you what you need to do: `comment` is not a valid attribute for `Comment`. So you can't do `Comment(comment=...)`. If you look at `Comment`, you'll see that you defined a field `comments`, not `comment`. Meaning python is expecting `Comment(comments=...)`.

Comment: Genius!..thank you so much! Nearly there...the only bit that doesn't work is this now: return redirect('index')...it comes up with a "Name error:" >  
name 'redirect' is not defined

Comment: I tried: return redirect('guestbook/index.html') ...but the same error

Comment: How you import redirect? Is this way `from django.shortcuts import redirect`?

Comment: I tried that - but it says - cannot import name 'redirect_view' from guestbook.views

Comment: NO. In `views.py`

Comment: Have also tried import redirect_view - but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

Your post method should be in this way:

```
def sign(request):

 if request.method=='POST':
     form = CommentForm(request.POST)

     if form.is_valid():
         new_comment=form.save()

         return redirect('index')
 else:
     form = CommentForm()

 context={'form' : form}
 return render(request,'guestbook/sign.html',context)
```

Comment: This way is extremely recommend for beginners. If you read the official tutorial you'll see that they teach this manner.

Comment: I agree, but you should explain it.

Comment: The final piece to the puzzle is figuring out why the redirect doesn't work

Comment: @MissComputing you registred the name 'index' view on urls.py?

Comment: You mean ...in the main project's urls.py > from .views import redirect_view  ??

Comment: Try redirect('/index/')

Comment: Worked! Thanks all very much!